# дополнительная таблица во вложенном запросе mysql

Tags: mysql

Есть запрос:

```
UPDATE requests SET status = 'В работе' WHERE id IN (SELECT id_request FROM resolutions WHERE name > 0)
```

В целом он делает то что мне нужно, но мне хотелось бы проверять не только таблицу resolutions но и другую по условию.

Например:

```
UPDATE requests SET status = 'В работе' WHERE id IN (SELECT id_request FROM resolutions WHERE name > 0 AND id_request FROM responsibility WHERE name > 0)
```

Выглядит топорно, и разумеется не работает хотя бы по тому, что вложение должно вернуть 1 результат что бы присвоить его полю id.

Как то так. Есть идеи ? можно попробовать что нибудь с применением JOIN.

Comment: А вы хотите получить id которые есть одновременно в обоих таблицах или которые есть хотя бы в одной из них ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Если нужны записи которые одновременно есть в обоих таблицах и в обоих таблицах name>0, то:

```
UPDATE requests SET status = 'В работе'
 WHERE id IN (
   SELECT A.id_request FROM resolutions A, responsibility B
    WHERE A.name > 0 AND A.id_request=B.id_request and B.name > 0
 )
```

Если же надо получить id которые есть хотя бы в одной из таблиц, то:

```
UPDATE requests SET status = 'В работе'
 WHERE id IN (
   SELECT id_request FROM resolutions    WHERE name > 0
    union
   SELECT id_request FROM responsibility WHERE name > 0
 )
```

Comment: Работает, хотя я пытался применить схожую конструкцию без А. и B. хотя бы думал в правильном направлении ) Пригодился первый вариант.

Comment: Ну да, можно без A и B, только во всех условиях лениво писать полные названия таблиц :)